# PFUser current User Parse

Tags: ios, parse-platform

**Edit**

The code in question and 'this here ... because only by changing the parameters PfUser Current User in PfUser User, the app does not create problems ... I forgot to indicate the type of Crash ...

```
-(void) {RichiamaDatiInattesa


PFQuery *EsamiInAttesa = [PFQuery queryWithClassName: @ "EsamiInAttesa"];

[EsamiInAttesa whereKey: @ "user" equalTo: [PFUser currentUser]];** //This is the problem Crash "Equal To: [PFUser currentUser]

[EsamiInAttesa countObjectsInBackgroundWithTarget: self selector: @ selector (countcallback: error :)];}
```

This' crash that returns the Log

**U 03/08/2013 00:04:10.650 [20120:907]**  Terminating app two to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can not do a comparison for query type: (null)'
 **First throw call stack:
(0x31a703e7 0x3976b963 0x31a70307 0xcdb6b 0xbba53 0xa939d 0xa9117 0x3389e579 0x338ded59 0x338daaf5 0x3391c1e1 0x338df803 0x338d7833 0x3387fd1f 0x3387f7ad 0x3387f1ef 0x355975f7 0x35597227 0x31a453e7 0x31a4538b 0x31a4420f 0x319b723d 0x319b70c9 0x338d646d 0x338d32b9 0xa89bd 0x39b98b20)
libc + + abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception**

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

I'm working PARSE (spectacular) but I can not figure out where I'm wrong because I continually from this CRASH .... : (

Terminating apt two to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can not do a comparison for query type: (null)'

If I modify this query "equal to [PFUser current user] in [PFUser user] does not return the application problems and it works perfectly, except that when I open the application, the first page I need you to give me the values ​​of the current user and this is not 'possible if instead of current user only insert user ...

**The problem occurs when I run the LOGOUT the time the user and try to log in again ... at this time the application CRASH ... Not even the screen displays PF Login**

The code 'this, can you tell me where I'm wrong? thanks to all

```
- (void) {RichiamaDatiInattesa
    
PFQuery EsamiInAttesa * = [PFQuery queryWithClassName: @ "EsamiInAttesa"];
     [EsamiInAttesa whereKey: @ "user" equalTo: [PFUser currentUser]];
     [EsamiInAttesa countObjectsInBackgroundWithTarget: self selector: @ selector (countcallback: error :)];
}


- (void) countcallback: (NSNumber *) count error: (NSError *) error {
     if (error) {
         self.DisplayNumero.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @ "% d tests are currently pending," [count intValue]];
          

     Else {}

         self.DisplayNumero.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @ "Connection Absent"];
        / * [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @ "Missing Information"
                                     message: @ "Make sure you fill out all of the information!"
                                    delegate: nil
                           cancelButtonTitle: @ "ok"
                           otherButtonTitles: nil] show]; * /
        }

    
}
```

Comment: Can you copy your actual code. Is the `if` actually wrong (where you check the error but do the opposite)? Which line throws the exception?

Comment: The issue is when no user is logged in at all? Or with a temporary user?

Comment: The moment I connect and code and 'present [PFUser current user] the application works as it should, it returns the right values ​​logged on user. When the user runs the offline Logout and try again riconettersi the application crashes with the error that I specified.

Comment: The problem does not occur if I enter [PFUser user] instead of [PFUser current user] but in doing so the application does not return me the values ​​of the logged

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to check if there is a currently logged in user before trying to perform any operations that require one. If `[PFUser currentUser] == nil` then you should not create and try to run your `PFQuery` because there is no current user to generate it with.

---

You could try:

```
- (void)RichiamaDatiInattesa {
    if ([PFUser currentUser] != nil) {
        PFQuery EsamiInAttesa * = [PFQuery queryWithClassName: @ "EsamiInAttesa"];
        [EsamiInAttesa whereKey: @ "user" equalTo: [PFUser currentUser]];
        [EsamiInAttesa countObjectsInBackgroundWithTarget: self selector: @ selector (countcallback: error :)];
    } else {
        [self countcallback:0 error:nil];
    }
}
```

---

When the user is logging in, be sure that `RichiamaDatiInattesa` method is called once the login is complete (if its done in the background).

Comment: I'm trying to understand, forgive me :) but I'm a little new with these steps .. so far and 'went well, but now I can not understand ... can you help me understand specifically what should I do?

Thank you very much :)

Comment: Wain thank you very much! now works does not gives me more 'crash the app ... I do not understand only one thing ... At first I performed as soon as you log in, the label containing the current data the time the user is immediately upgraded ... Now it gives me a value of 0 and to update I have to go to the next view and go back ... How come?
Thank you very much still six I think ...

Comment: How do you can after login? Are you sure the login is complete when you call?

Comment: I just entered as the file to parse ... As soon as I log does not give me any value and when I try to do an action with a button in the view returns me this LOG

Comment: U 03/08/2013 01:23:16.265 [20411:907] *** Terminating app two to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '- [Login ShowPanel:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1e044220'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x31a703e7 0x3976b963 0x31a73f31 0x31a7264d 0x319ca208 0x3396a087 0x3396a03b 0x3396a015 0x339698cb 0x33969db9 0x338925f9 0x3387f8e1 0x3387f1ef 0x355975f7 0x35597227 0x31a453e7 0x31a4538b 0x31a4420f 0x319b723d 0x319b70c9 0x3559633b 0x338d32b9 0x4c9fd 0x39b98b20)
libc + + abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

Comment: Sorry my mistake ... and crash 'due to the fact that I had commented on the action "ShowPanel" .. sorry but I can certainly understand the chaos that I have in my brain now :)

The only thing that it 'remained as I told you and' just data loading at login that still does not look right ... i from a value of 0 when it should be 15

Comment: I plugged in my viewDidLoad
[self performSelector: @ selector (RichiamaDatiInattesa)];

Could this be the cause?

Comment: Yes, you can call it there but also call it when the login actually changes.

Comment: Perfect! inserted in the method willappearance ... now it works just login first ... Wain Thank you so much you have been very kind ... unfortunately few have the patience to follow who and 'the first steps: (

Thank you very much!